# Why Hibernate Envers not firing up on update?

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, audit, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers to audit log my tables and it is configured using Spring. However when update, modify or delete action is conducted no auditing occurs. Following are the configurations.

Spring configuration

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
            <prop key="SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>

            <!--envers config-->
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_AUDITING</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">revision_id</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">revision_type</prop>

            <!--envers listners-->
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
```

And I have added the @Audited annotation to the entity class. I'm using Hibernate core 3.5.0-Final and same version for envers.

When I check the hibernate logged sqls, I can see the update query has executed but not any query to insert data to audit table. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you seeing XML hibernate-mappings being written to standard out during bootup?  What I'd like to confirm is whether or not Envers is even generating the audit entity mappings.

Comment: I removed all above configurations and let it to be run in default settings with @Audited annotation in the entity class. Even that it didn't complain about missing tables since I'm not using ddl.auto to update/create. Hibernate is working fine and problem is with Envers

Comment: You do have to configure the event listeners per the documentation when using any version prior to ORM 4.3.  But otherwise properly configuring the listeners and having the jar on the classpath should be sufficient for Envers to begin auditing annotated entities.

Comment: I checked with envers 5.2 as well. Same results. I was assuming that listners are not properly configured. I found these when searching as well.           <property name="eventListeners">
<map>
<entry key="post-insert" >
<bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
</entry>
<entry key="post-update">
<bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
</entry>
<entry key="post-delete">
<bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
</entry>
</map>
</property>

Comment: Just to be clear, when using Envers 4.3+ (which includes 5.x) you don't need to register any listeners.  This happens automatically when the `hibernate-envers` artifact is found on the classpath and is bootstrapped as a part of Hibernate ORM's bootstrap process.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when changing org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Makes sense, glad you figured it out.

Comment: Thanks you your guidance :)